# Regulating fares in the UK transport system - who can unfair 'unregulated' fares be reported to?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, regulations

I went to book a train from South Wales to Yorkshire and the tickets cost £363. This is obscene and completely beyond its true market value. It is the same price as a flight from UK to USA.

I have been trying to find out if there is watchdog or regulator of some sort in the UK that deals with fair consumer pricing in the transport system so I can report this to them (like an Ofgem equivalent for transport to ensure service providers don't overcharge consumers.)

However I am very confused about the set up of the transport system, how prices are set and by who, and how they are regulated and by who.

The two trainlines in question here are Great Western Railway and Cross Country.

I have found the following [ORR](https://www.orr.gov.uk/monitoring-regulation/rail/passengers/tickets-and-fares/fares-and-penalty-fares) who explains this difference between regulated and unregulated trainlines:

"Some fares are regulated by government, who controls their price, while others are not, and train operators are free to set them."

On the unregulated ones, they continue:

"Train operators employ a commercial strategy in setting fares. If a train operator's commercial strategy runs contrary to the broader public interest, it is for the government to consider as part of its fares policy.

We enforce the Competition Act 1998, which makes it illegal for companies to do certain things, such as use their powerful position in the market to take advantage of consumers or fix prices. We may conduct an investigation if we have reasonable grounds to suspect the law has been broken."

Surely charging almost £400 for a train ticket from South Wales to Yorkshire is;

1. A commercial strategy that "runs contrary to the broader public interest" and
2. An example of a company using "their powerful position in the market to take advantage of consumer"

I say this because nobody in their right mind would willingly pay this for an in-country train ticket from Wales to Yorkshire.. and I'm fairly certain most people couldn't even afford to do so. Somebody that needs to travel there as quickly as possible (bus takes 8-11 hours) in an emergency and has no other way of getting there (ie. Can't drive) would have no choice but to pay this obscene price which is grossly unfair.

Based on the above quotes taken from ORR, is this something that could be reported to:

1.) A government regulatory body (and if so who?) - "it is for the government to consider as part of its fares policy (ORR)

Or

2.) ORR - "We may conduct an investigation if we have reasonable grounds to suspect the law has been broken."

Comment: Doesn't the UK government run the train system?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch It's complicated. The train operators were essentially franchisees, some fares regulated and others not. But then COVID made running trains uneconomic, so we had the unlikely spectacle of a Conservative government nationalising them to go with big handouts and tax rises. Strange times.

Comment: An off-peak train from Cardiff to Leeds tomorow is £71. I am pretty sure you can't fly to America for that.

Comment: @weatherVane and an off peak from pontypool to Middlesbrough is £182. We can all cherry pick data

Comment: I didn't cherry pick it. I looked up the first journey I thought of.

Comment: The question seems more of a rant than a SE question.

Comment: @weatherVane it's on topic and asks a specific question. Comments are for clarifying the question, is there something you need to clarify or are you just bored?